# Combining the respective columns from 2 separate DataFrames using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 large DataFrames with the same set of columns but different values. I need to combine the values in respective columns (A and B here, maybe be more in actual data) into single values in the same columns (see required output below). I have a quick way of implementing this using `np.vectorize` and `df.to_numpy()` but I am looking for a way to implement this **strictly with pandas**. Criteria here is **first readability of code then time complexity**.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[5,4,3,2,1]})
print(df1)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  4
2  3  3
3  4  2
4  5  1
```

and,

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40,50], 'B':[50,40,30,20,10]})
print(df2)
```

```
    A   B
0  10  50
1  20  40
2  30  30
3  40  20
4  50  10
```

I have one way of doing it which is quite fast -

```
#This function might change into something more complex
def conc(a,b):
    return str(a)+'_'+str(b)

conc_v = np.vectorize(conc)

required = pd.DataFrame(conc_v(df1.to_numpy(), df2.to_numpy()), columns=df1.columns)
print(required)
```

```
#Required Output
      A     B
0  1_10  5_50
1  2_20  4_40
2  3_30  3_30
3  4_40  2_20
4  5_50  1_10
```

Looking for an alternate way (strictly pandas) of solving this.

Comment: You have a solution that is fast, but you're looking for one that is more readable?

Comment: The more readable with pandas could be `df1.astype(str) + '_' + df2.astype(str)`?

Comment: @LarsSkaug exactly

Comment: @Ben.T yea that's great! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Criteria here is first readability of code

Another simple way is using `add` and [`radd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html)

```
df1.astype(str).add(df2.astype(str).radd('-'))
```

---

```
     A     B
0  1-10  5-50
1  2-20  4-40
2  3-30  3-30
3  4-40  2-20
4  5-50  1-10
```